# Common root questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> The value of $a$ for which the equations $x^3+ax+1=0$ and $x^4+ax^2+1=0$ have a common root has to be found.

I tried by subtracting the two equations then I converted them in factors which come out to be $x(x^2+a)(x-1)=0$.

Now what to do?

Comment: subtracting is not a right way of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the gcd with the Euclidean algorithm:
\begin{align}
x^4+ax^2+1&=x(x^3+ax+1)+(-x+1)\\[4px]
x^3+ax+1&=(-x^2-x-a-1)(-x+1)+a+2
\end{align}
If $a+2\ne0$, the polynomials are coprime.

Can you finish?

---

Alternative method: the resultant is
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & a & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & a & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & a & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & a & 1 \\
1 & 0 & a & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & a & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & a & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=a+2
$$

Comment: Can you help me understand how the second eqn came?

Comment: @user532267 The Euclidean algorithm applied to $A$ and $B$ is: set $R_0=B$; compute the remainder $R_1$ of the division $A=R_0Q_1+R_1$; compute the remainder $R_2$ of the division $R_0=R_1Q_2+R_2$; go on in the same way until you get a remainder $0$. The last nonzero remainder is the gcd.

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$x^4+ax^2+1-x(x^3+ax+1)=1-x.$$
Hence a common root $x$ of the equations $x^3+ax+1=0$ and $x^4+ax^2+1=0$ should solve also the equation $1-x=0$. It follows that the only possible common root is $x=1$. Can you take it form here?

Answer (score 1):

A common root will be a root of the difference - so what are the roots of the difference (they are rather visible now you have factorised it)?

But it will also be a root of the original equations. So which of those roots can solve the original pair of equations (substitute back in)? And what value(s) of $a$ does that imply?

Polynomial division as per egreg's (and partly Robert Z's) answer - the Euclidean Algorithm for polynomials - will find you the highest common factor of the two - it subtracts the right multiple, and isn't just opportunistic. Using that eliminates some of the "false" roots. But your method works fine with care.

Comment: Fine. now I tried putting those back in the original equations both none them solve it.

Comment: OK. fine with the new post

Comment: "now I tried putting those back in the original equations both none them solve it."  One of them does.  If you plug $x = 1$ back into the two equations you get $a+2 = 0$ for both equations. If $a =-2$ then $x^4 - 2x^2 + 1$ and $x^3 - 2x +1$ but have a common root at $x=1$.  That solves it.... *if* $a = -2$.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you did subtract

If $x^3 + ax + 1= 0 = x^4 + ax^2 + 1 = 0$ then $x^4 - x^3 +a^2x + ax = x(x^2 + a)(1-x)= 0$ so either $x = 0; x=1;$ or $x = \sqrt{-a}$.

If $x = 0$ then $x^3 + ax + 1 = x^4 + ax^2 + 1 = 1 \ne 0$ so that was an extraneous root added.

If $x = 1$ then $x^3 + ax + 1 = a+ 2 = 0$ and $x^4 + ax + 1 = a+2 = 0$.  So $a$ must be $a = -2$.

If $x= \sqrt{-a}$ then $x^2 + ax + 1 = -a\sqrt{-a} + a\sqrt{-a} + 1 = 1 \ne 0$ so that was an extraneous root added.

So the only possible common root is $x =1$ and for that to be a common root we must have $a = -2$.

Subtracting added extraneous roots so perhaps there is a more efficient way.  No matter.  It did work.